# Git server hook: get contents of files being pushed?

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to enforce some coding rules in my team. To that end, I've written a number of client-side hooks, which work all right, but now I want the same checks to run when a developer pushes their modifications to the central repository. But they don't work.

Here is what I want to do:

I want to traverse the pushed files line by line, check for coding conventions violations and if I find any, reject the push, also showing the line numbers + violations.

In my pre-commit client side hook I was able to do that by calling `git diff --cached --name-status --diff-filter=AM` to get the list of modified files, and `git cat-file -p :filename` for each of the files retrieved in the first call to get the whole text of the files.

When I try to do the same in my server-side `update` hook, I get an empty string (for the list of the files).

I also tried calling `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only newrev` (where newrev is the SHA I get as a parameter to the update hook, `git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id <tree-ish>`, and some other things I find on the net, but I can't get a clear understanding of what is going on and what I should call.

Can you help me?

Comment: What are the benefits of using `git cat-file` over `cat`. I tried to search but  unable to fine a compelling reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make changes to your script because there's no working copy on the server side, and `git diff --cached` works with a staging area (or index), while your index is empty when the server receives a push.

Simply use `git diff --name-status <sha-old> <sha-new>` instead, with `sha-old` and `sha-new` being the refs sent to the hooks as an argument, and you'll get the same output as running `git diff --cached` before a commit.

As for checking file content, you can use `git show sha-new:/path/to/file`

Comment: Strangely, I still get an empty string... I don't know if it matters, but I am pushing into an empty remote, and while I push, git says it is "Writing 27 objects", that is it seems that the push is not empty.

Comment: After pushing my first commit there, now I can push and I do get the file list. Thanks a lot!