# How do I access the contents and names of files being committed from within a Git hook script?

Tags: python, git, hook

I'm a bit confused about how to implement git hooks correctly, and I cannot figure out how to access any type of information that I need from within my script. I have very little experience scripting/using Python.

I simply want to access the filenames of the files (and later also the contents of the file) about to be committed in a pre-commit hook, so that I can check if they match a naming convention. I've seen posts such as this one [Git server hook: get contents of files being pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314527), where the poster mentions how he got a list of the files by calling `git diff --cached --name-status --diff-filter=AM`.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do I call this line from within my script and set it equal to something? I recognize that line as a Git command but I'm confused how that translates into coding it. What does it look like in python?

Here's all I currently have for a template for my pre-commit. It simply does a test print and its in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print("\nError details\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git diff-index --name-status HEAD | grep '^[MA]'
```

That's the most reliable way I know.  It prints out the names with an M or A prefix, followed by some whitespace, followed by the name, to indicate whether or not the file was "modified" or "added."

There is some extra magic, though.  I would recommend:

```
git stash --keep-index
git diff-index --name-status HEAD | grep '^[MA]'
git reset --hard
git stash pop --quiet --index
```

This will give you the list of names *in your staging area* (by stashing any changes since your last `git add` command) and restore your workspace back immediately afterward.  Since your staging area, and not your workspace, is what you're about to commit, this is probably what you want.

I have a program that does all this at https://github.com/elfsternberg/pre-commit-stash

It's written in Hy, a dialect of Python that most people barely know about or can even read.  Hy does come with a hy2py transpiler, though, so if you really need it, this script will show you how it's done.